# Hyphenation at gender stars, gender gaps, etc

Tags: hyphenation

### Background

Some natural languages have recently seen the addition of gender neutrality emphasis. For example, in German, almost all nouns referring to occupations have a grammatically masculine and grammatical feminine form: the word *Wissenschaftler* (“scientist”) can be understood to refer to all scientists irrespective of sex and gender (under the “generic masculine reading”), but some prefer to emphasise that the term also refers to non-male scientists by appending the grammatically feminine suffix (*Wissenschaftlerin* is “female scientist”, so *-in* is the suffix for fem. in this case) **plus** a divider to emphasise not only male and female scientists, but non-binary scientists as well.

There are at least four gender methods in active use in German:

- gender gap: Wissenschaftler_in
- gender asterisk: Wissenschafler*in
- gender dot: Wissenschaftler·in
- gender colon: Wissenschaftler:in

### Problem

How can LaTeX be taught to take these dividers into account when hyphenating?

As far as I know, hyphenation of gender dividers is currently not covered in standard grammar rules for German. That is, it seems currently unclear whether gender dividers can be used instead of a line-breaking hyphen. So I'm asking for both cases.

#### Sub-problem 1

How can LaTeX be taught to treat dividers as hyphen points? In other words, how can I allow hyphenation at `-`, `\_`, and `*` in these examples?

```latex
Wis-sen-schaft-ler\_in
Wis-sen-schaft-ler*in
```

(`babel` would hyphen `Wis-sen-schaft-ler-in` and `Wis-sen-schaft-ler` by default)

#### Sub-problem 2

In standard documents, the dividers prevent any hyphenation. How can LaTeX be taught to ignore these dividers and use the hyphenation from the base form? For example, how can I allow hyphenation at `-` in `Wis-sen-schaft-ler\_in`?